# What strategy do I use to avoid global variables in ruby?

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I'm learning Ruby through 'Learn to Program' by Chris Pine. I'm trying to cope without global variables. I have a sloppy looking command prompt blackjack program (can't split yet) My first three methods illustrate the problem I'm having. In Pascal I would have used global variables, and used methods to manipulate those global variables. It would look something like this (using ruby pseudo language)

```
$deck_of_cards = []
$player_hand   = []
$dealer_hand   = []

def create_deck
    $deck_of_cards = #numbers 1-52
end

def shuffle_deck
    $deck_of_cards = #shuffled up deck of cards
end

def opening_deal
    2.times do
        $player_hand.push $deck_of_cards.pop
        $dealer_hand.push $deck_of_cards.pop
    end
end

create_deck
shuffle_deck
opening_deal
```

and I would end up with a shuffled deck, a player hand, and a dealer hand.

Taking away global variables, the first two methods now look like this:

```
def create_deck deck_of_cards
    deck_of_cards = #numbers 1-52
    return deck_of_cards
end

def shuffle_deck deck_of_cards
    deck_of_cards = #shuffled up deck of cards
    return deck_of_cards
end

deck = create_deck([])
deck = shuffle_deck(deck)
```

which feels a little odd but I could get used to it.

But I'm completely stuck on the last method, which would need to return two variables, player_hand and dealer_hand.  I could push those two arrays into another array and return that, but that doesn't seem like it's simplifying anything.

Is there a general strategy for dealing with this, or does each situation have its own unique solution?

Another situation that comes to mind is a chess program.  Why would it not make sense to make the chess board a global variable since almost all methods in a chess program would need to use it's value?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: Objects. Object oriented programming allows you to encapsulate data so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. As your projects grow larger, it becomes unmaintainable to have all your data in the global namespace. Objects allow you to group data  and methods into meaningful units, which can then be re-used and maintained more easily.

So for instance with the example you provided we could make deck and hand objects. This then allows us to create multiple deck and hands easily because these objects encapsulate and manage their data.

As a rough outline of how you might organize your classes / methods:

```
class Deck
  def shuffle
  end

  def draw_hand
  end
end

class Hand
end

class Card
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, using object oriented programming techniques you would define classes and create objects of those classes and then pass around those objects.  You can think of objects as sort of like arrays in that they can contain lots of related data, but better than arrays in that the data elements can have names and can be any type and do not need to be the same type and they come with named functions for operating on the data.  (Actually, in Ruby, Array elements can be any type and do not need to be the same type, and the same is true of Hash elements plus Hash elements have names, but Ruby is special that way.  Few other languages allow that.)

Keeping it simple, though, you can continue your program like this:

```
def opening_deal deck_of_cards
    player_hand = []
    dealer_hand = []
    2.times do
        player_hand.push deck_of_cards.pop
        dealer_hand.push deck_of_cards.pop
    end
    return player_hand, dealer_hand
end

player_hand, dealer_hand = opening_deal deck
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad habit to have global variables, but it is not bad to have global constants, or in other words, constants defined in the main name space. When in need of a global variable, you can always define a constant in the main name space. Mutable objects like string, hash, array can be modified even if it is a constant. If that is not enough and you need more complicated things, then you can define a module (which is a special case of constants), and define methods on that module to have access to the things you want to do, and encapsulate the complicated information inside that module using instance variables.