# Ruby Name Error

Tags: ruby

I wrote a script to do some calculations that I previously had in a spreadsheet. Here is my code:

```
#Ruby
require '../file/fromFile'

input = commaSep('gen.txt')

civil = input[0]
economy = input[1]
political = input[2]
tax = input[3]
taxMod = input[4]
production = input[5]
population = input[6]
admin = input[7]

#debug puts
puts civil
puts economy
puts political
puts tax
puts taxMod
puts production
puts population
puts admin

TOUT_CONST = 5076287515610300

def workerEnthusiasm ()
  1 + civil + political + taxMod
end
def consumerConfidence ()
  1 + economy + civil
end
def adminBudgetCurve ()
  if admin - 0.3 > 0 then
    signAdmin = 1
  elsif admin - 0.3 == 0 then
    signAdmin = 0
  elsif admin - 0.3 < 0 then
    signAdmin = -1
  end
  return 1 - admin * signAdmin * ((admin - 0.3).abs ** (1 / 3)) + 0.2 + admin
end
def govEfficiency ()
  1 + political / adminBudgetCurve()
end
def output ()
  production * population * workerEnthusiasm() * consumerConfidence()
end
def consumption ()
  output() * (1 - tax)
end
def govBudget ()
  output() * govEfficiency() * (tax + consumerConfidence() / 10 + workerEnthusiasm() / 40)
end
def govExpenditure ()
  govBudget() * govEfficiency()
end
def govWaste ()
  govBudget() - govExpenditure()
end
def imports ()
  ((1 / consumerConfidence()) / 8) * (consumption() + govExpenditure())
end
def exports ()
  64970419915908 * (output() / TOUT_CONST)
end
def netTrade ()
  exports() - imports()
end
def GDP ()
  govBudget() + netTrade() + govExpenditure
end
def GDPPC ()
  GDP() / population
end
def exchangeRate ()
  Math.sqrt(GDPPC() * production / 40400000)
end
def unemployment ()
  ((GDPPC() - 37500) ** 2) * 1.25 * (10 ** -10) - 1.5 * (10 ** -6) * (GDPPC() - 37500) + 0.03
end

puts unemployment()
```

When I run the code, I get a NameError. Here is the terminal output:

```
0.03
0.03
0.01
0.25
0.04
30000
241401636
0.05
gen.rb:45:in `output': undefined local variable or method `production' for main:Object (NameError)
    from gen.rb:51:in `govBudget'
    from gen.rb:69:in `GDP'
    from gen.rb:72:in `GDPPC'
    from gen.rb:78:in `unemployment'
    from gen.rb:81:in `&lt;main>'
```

It seems like the error is in the output function but I can't figure out why.

Comment: When you refer to an exception having been raised, it is important to provide all relevant information. Here, what raised the `NameError` exception and in which line of code did it occur? A careful reading of the exception message will often pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`production` is a local variable in the outer scope; it is unknown inside `output`. If you want to use global variables, they need to be marked as such: `$production`, but using global variables is almost always a bad idea. Or you can use instance variables, `@production`, which will set a variable on the object you are currently using (here, the main object). Or, you can use function parameters to pass the variables into the functions.

But unlike in JavaScript, for example, variables in outer scopes are not captured by `def` (but they are captured by, say, `lambda`).

```
a = 1

def f
  puts a
end
f
# => error

g = lambda do
  puts a
end
g.call
# => 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem!
If I may ask, why is using global variables a bad idea?

Comment: Orange, see, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756309/what-strategy-do-i-use-to-avoid-global-variables-in-ruby) and [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). I found these by Googling; you can do the same.